# How to get groups from a LaTex regex match?

Tags: l3regex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{expl3}


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\curl}{m}{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_extract_once:nnN  {\/([a-z0-9]{10})}  {#1} \l_uiy_result_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_uiy_result_seq {\href{#1}{##1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document} 

\curl{https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h60a3169h86816}

\end{document}
```

Using this code I'm getting match & match group one after one.

Example

```
\curl{https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h60a3169h86816}
```

Output is
[image]

Where First `/1a1c6e99h6` is match & second half is match group `1a1c6e99h6`

**How can I only map match group `1a1c6e99h6`**

Comment: Can you give us a compilable code?

Comment: Have you tried to pop the first element via `\seq_pop_left` before iterating on the sequence? The doc says : *"If it exists, the match is stored as the first item of the ⟨seq var⟩, and further items are the contents of capturing groups, in the order of their opening parenthesis. "*

Comment: That's the only code I'm using. Also `\seq_pop_left` is not working

Comment: Gives us a code with `\begin{document}`... etc. This will allow us to copy and paste your code in https://texlive.net/run to quickly try something...

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to pop left the sequence such as to obtain `1a1c6e99h6`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{expl3}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\curl}{m}{
    \regex_extract_once:nnN  {\/([a-z0-9]{10})}  {#1} \l_uiy_result_seq

    % One good example of use of l_tmpa_tl.
    \seq_pop_left:NNTF \l_uiy_result_seq \l_tmpa_tl {
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_uiy_result_seq {\href{#1}{##1}}
    }{
        No ~ match!
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document} 

\curl{https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h60a3169h86816}

\curl{PB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't want extraction, but just replacement:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{expl3}


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\curl}{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_once:nnN  {.*\/([a-z0-9]{10}).*} {\1} \l_tmpa_tl
    \href{#1}{\l_tmpa_tl}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document} 

\curl{https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h60a3169h86816}

\end{document}
```

[image]